# Error While Binding Sshd to Port 2222 During Update on Debian 10 "Buster"

Tags: debian, ssh, sshd

Got here following error output while updating:

`Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-server
 ssh
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Setting up openssh-server (1:7.9p1-10+deb10u1) ...
rescue-ssh.target is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript ssh, action "restart" failed.
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-10-14 12:57:57 -03; 7ms ago`
     `Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
  Process: 22241 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 22242 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
 Main PID: 22242 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)`

`Oct 14 12:57:57 wdbuster systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Oct 14 12:57:57 wdbuster sshd[22242]: error: Bind to port 2222 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 installed openssh-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ssh:
 ssh depends on openssh-server (>= 1:7.9p1-10+deb10u1); however:
  Package openssh-server is not configured yet.`

`dpkg: error processing package ssh (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-server
 ssh
Press Return to continue, 'q' followed by Return to quit.`

Then, `$ sudo dpkg --audit` returned following output:

`The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
 ssh                  secure shell client and server (metapackage)`

`The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 openssh-server       secure shell (SSH) server, for secure access from remote`

Considering too that port 22 is changed to 2222, on `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Any ideas?

Comment: “error: Bind to port 2222 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.” Something else (or perhaps a left-over SSH daemon) is already bound to the port...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One may proceed as follows:

`$ sudo systemctl disable sshd
 $ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
 $ sudo dpkg --configure openssh-server`

Then, finally

`$ systemctl enable sshd`